# SAPUI5 Export specific Rows

Tags: javascript, sapui5

In the OpenUI5 sample: [SAPUI5 SDK -Table Export](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.TableExport/preview), the export for all Rows is working fine.
Now I want to export specific rows, e.g. with Index 2 and 4. The problem is to assign the path.

The following adjustment is just returning an empty row:

```
rows : {
    path : "/ProductCollection/2"
},
```

How do you set specific rows for the Export?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others, facing the same Problem:

The workaround is, to declare a new JSON Model and pushing the wanted rows of the initial model in a loop to it.
Bind the new Model to the View and use it for the export function.

For example:

```
var aBindings = this.getView().byId("table").getBindingInfo("items").binding.aIndices;
var oExportModel = new JSONModel({
    data: {
        services:{
        }
    }
});

var aServices = [];
for (var iCounter = 0; iCounter < aBindings.length; iCounter++){
    var oService = this.getView().getModel("data").getProperty("/data/services/" + aBindings[iCounter]);
    aServices.push(oService);
}
oExportModel.setProperty("/data/services", aServices);
this.setModel(oExportModel, "exportModel");
```